# Howto use sed to remove only triple empty lines?

Tags: linux, sed

Howto use sed to remove only triple empty lines?

For example:

MyText.txt

```
line1

line2


line3



line4
```

**with the use of sed i want the result to look like this** 
MyText.txt

```
line1

line2


line3
line4
```

I was able to delete double empty lines with

```
sed -i '/^$/{
N
/^\n$/D
}' MyText.txt
```

However my goal is to delete triple empty lines and only triple empty lines.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's as simple as:

```
sed '1N;N;/^\n\n$/d;P;D'
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not sed, but it's a whole lot shorter than what you can do with sed:

```
$ printf 'a\nb\n\nc\n\n\nd\n' | 
  perl -e 'undef $/; $_ = <>; s/\n\n\n/\n/g; print'
a
b

c
d
```

Answer (score 2):

If you allow `awk` solutions, you could do it like this:

```
awk -v RS='\n\n\n\n' 1 Text.txt
```

Comment: very smart and concise.

Answer (score 0):

The following code removes only three (neither less nor more) consecutive empty lines:

```
$ printf "%s\n" foo "" bar "" "" baz "" "" "" cow "" "" "" "" moe |
      sed '
        /^$/{ 
            N;
            /^\n$/{
                N;
                /^\n\n$/{
                    $ d; 
                    N;
                    s/\n\n\n\(.\)/\1/
                }
            }
        }' 
foo

bar


baz
cow




moe
```