# How to use sed to remove only double empty lines?

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I found this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651591/howto-use-sed-to-remove-only-triple-empty-lines) on how to remove triple empty lines. However, I need the same only for double empty lines. Ie. all double blank lines should be deleted completely, but single blank lines should be kept.

I know a bit of sed, but the proposed command for removing triple blank lines is over my head:

`sed '1N;N;/^\n\n$/d;P;D'`

Comment: what about triple and more blank lines?

Comment: @xdazz: yes it would be ok for triple or more blank lines.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I've commented the `sed` command you don't understand:

```
sed '
    ## In first line: append second line with a newline character between them.
    1N;
    ## Do the same with third line.
    N;
    ## When found three consecutive blank lines, delete them. 
    ## Here there are two newlines but you have to count one more deleted with last "D" command.
    /^\n\n$/d;
    ## The combo "P+D+N" simulates a FIFO, "P+D" prints and deletes from one side while "N" appends
    ## a line from the other side.
    P;
    D
'
```

Remove `1N` because we need only two lines in the 'stack' and it's enought with the second `N`, and change `/^\n\n$/d;` to `/^\n$/d;` to delete all two consecutive blank lines.

A test:

Content of `infile`:

```
1


2
3

4



5

6


7
```

Run the `sed` command:

```
sed '
    N;
    /^\n$/d;
    P;
    D
' infile
```

That yields:

```
1
2
3

4

5

6
7
```

Comment: For all wanting to use this, don't forget the `sed -i` option to change that immediately in the file instead of sending the result to the out stream.

Comment: on macOS, this deletes the last line of the file (even when that line is non-blank)

Comment: Good Explanation, but the regex part can be more clear. "Here there are two newlines but you have to count one more deleted", the /^\n\n$/d;  has already delete 3 blank lines.(note 3 blank lines has two \n) The last 'D' operates on 'pattern space'.  D-command removes pattern space and left only one line(without \n). -- Then sed start  next cyclic, jump to the beginning and what the N does, is appending \n to pattern space then loading next line.

Answer (score 77):

This would be easier with `cat`:

```
cat -s
```

Comment: Nice one, but it doesn't do exactly the same. However, I didn't know this option and it is very useful, so thanks anyway.

Answer (score 9):

```
sed '/^$/{N;/^\n$/d;}'
```

It will delete only two consecutive blank lines in a file. You can use this expression only in file then only you can fully understand. When a blank line will come that it will enter into braces.

Normally sed will read one line. `N` will append the second line to pattern space. If that line is empty line. the both lines are separated by newline.

`/^\n$/` this pattern will match that time only the `d` will work. Else `d` not work. `d` is used to delete the pattern space whole content then start the next cycle.

Comment: I've tried this command and it removes excess newlines (some of the multiple newlines are removed altogether rather than replaced by a single newline). I'm not really sure why this happens, so beware.

Comment: sed 'N;/^\n$/D;P;D;'  seems to work better and deletes only consecutive newlines

Answer (score 8):

This would be easier with `awk`:

```
awk -v RS='\n\n\n' 1
```

Answer (score 1):

BUT the above solution only deletes first search of 3 consecutive blank line.
To delete all, 3 consecutive blank lines use below command

```
sed '1N;N;/^\n\n$/ { N;s/^\n\n//;N;D; };P;D' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell none of the solutions here work. `cat -s` as suggested by @DerMike isn't POSIX compliant (and it's less convenient if you're already using `sed` for another transformation), and `sed 'N;/^\n$/d;P;D'` as suggested by @Birei sometimes deletes more newlines than it should.

Instead, `sed ':L;N;s/^\n$//;t L'` works. For POSIX compliance use `sed -e :L -e N -e 's/^\n$//' -e 't L'`, since POSIX doesn't specify using `;` to separate commands.

Example:

```sh
$ S='foo\nbar\n\nbaz\n\n\nqux\n\n\n\nquxx\n';\
> paste <(printf "$S")\
>       <(printf "$S" | sed -e 'N;/^\n$/d;P;D')\
>       <(printf "$S" | sed -e ':L;N;s/^\n$//;t L')
foo     foo     foo
bar     bar     bar
                
baz     baz     baz
        qux     
                qux
qux     quxx    
                quxx
                
                
quxx            
$
```

Here we can see the original file, @Birei's solution, and my solution side-by-side. @Birei's solution deletes all blank lines separating `baz` and `qux`, while my solution removes all but one as intended.

Explanation:

```
:L        Create a new label called L.

N         Read the next line into the current pattern space,
          separated by an "embedded newline."

s/^\n$//  Replace the pattern space with the empty pattern space,
          corresponding to a single non-embedded newline in the output,
          if the current pattern space only contains a single embedded newline,
          indicating that a blank line was read into the pattern space by `N`
          after a blank line had already been read from the input.

t L       Branch to label L if the previous `s` command successfully
          substituted text in the pattern space.
```

In effect, this deletes one recurrent blank line at a time, reading each into the pattern space as an embedded newline with `N` and deleting them with `s`.

Answer (score -1):

BUT the above solution only deletes first search of 3 consecutive blank line. To delete all, 3 consecutive blank lines use below command

**sed '1N;N;/^\n\n$/ { N;s/^\n\n//;N;D; };P;D' filename**

Comment: I understand that you have created 2 accounts. Now I suggest you keep the other one and have that one deleted. hint: you can change account name after creation

Answer (score -2):

Just pipe it to 'uniq' command and all empty lines regardless the number of them will be shrank to just one. Simpler is better.

Clarification: As Marlar stated this is not a solution if you have "other non-blank consecutive duplicated lines" that you do not want to get rid of. This *is* a solution in other cases like when trying to cleanup configuration files which was the solution I was after when I saw this question. I solved my problem indeed just using 'uniq'.

Comment: Sometimes it can be too simple, though! If the source contains duplicate entries they would be removed too. That is not an acceptable solution.